# Splitting a string to view stats

Tags: json, string, split

If I wanted to convert the stats in json to a readable list, how would I do that?

For example,

```
{
    "player_stat_summary": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "stats": {
                "id": 1,
                "average_node_capture_assist": 0,
                "max_node_neutralize_assist": 0,
                "total_minion_kills": 0,
                "max_champions_killed": 0,
                "total_champion_kills": 0,
                "average_champions_killed": 0,
                "average_num_deaths": 0,
                "max_node_capture": 0,
                "max_objective_player_score": 0,
                "total_neutral_minions_killed": 0,
                "max_assists": 0,
                "average_combat_player_score": 0,
                "max_node_capture_assist": 0,
                "average_objective_player_score": 0,
                "max_team_objective": 0,
                "total_assists": 0,
                "average_node_capture": 0,
                "average_total_player_score": 0,
                "average_team_objective": 0,
                "average_node_neutralize": 0,
                "max_node_neutralize": 0,
                "average_node_neutralize_assist": 0,
                "average_assists": 0,
                "max_total_player_score": 0,
                "max_combat_player_score": 0,
                "total_turrets_killed": 0,
                "total_node_neutralize": 0,
                "total_node_capture": 0
            },
            "player_stat_summary_type": "Coop",
            "wins": 100,
            "losses": 0
        }
    ],
    "time_stamp": "2015-05-22T15:54:43.069814Z",
    "summoner_id": 0
}
```

Comment: I'd like to use dot notation but am unsure how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what language you are using.

Assuming JS.

you can use [`JSON.parse(text)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

so assuming that your JSON string is stored in a variable called `text`

```
var stats= JSON.parse(text);

console.log(stats.player_stat_summary[0].id);
    > 1
```

However, it looks like that's not a string at all,but is actually already an object. You're just not assigning it to a variable. If this is the case, just assign it to a variable and use it as I did above, no need for `JSON.parse(text);`

e.g.

```
stats={....};
console.log(stats.player_stat_summary[0].id);
    > 1
```

Comment: sorry, i am using JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over the stats and emit an HTML list you could do something like the following:

```js
var stats = {
    "player_stat_summary": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "stats": {
                "id": 1,
                "average_node_capture_assist": 0,
                "max_node_neutralize_assist": 0,
                "total_minion_kills": 0,
                "max_champions_killed": 0,
                "total_champion_kills": 0,
                "average_champions_killed": 0,
                "average_num_deaths": 0,
                "max_node_capture": 0,
                "max_objective_player_score": 0,
                "total_neutral_minions_killed": 0,
                "max_assists": 0,
                "average_combat_player_score": 0,
                "max_node_capture_assist": 0,
                "average_objective_player_score": 0,
                "max_team_objective": 0,
                "total_assists": 0,
                "average_node_capture": 0,
                "average_total_player_score": 0,
                "average_team_objective": 0,
                "average_node_neutralize": 0,
                "max_node_neutralize": 0,
                "average_node_neutralize_assist": 0,
                "average_assists": 0,
                "max_total_player_score": 0,
                "max_combat_player_score": 0,
                "total_turrets_killed": 0,
                "total_node_neutralize": 0,
                "total_node_capture": 0
            },
            "player_stat_summary_type": "Coop",
            "wins": 100,
            "losses": 0
        }
    ],
    "time_stamp": "2015-05-22T15:54:43.069814Z",
    "summoner_id": 0
}

function emitStats(s) {
  // create a new UL
  var list = document.createElement('ul');
  
  // iterate over the properties
  Object.keys(s).forEach(function(statName) {
    // create an LI for the property
    var el = document.createElement('li');
    // fill it with the stat name and value
    el.innerHTML = statName.replace(/_/g,' ') + ": " + s[statName];
    // add it to the UL
    list.appendChild(el);
  });
  // add the UL to the document.
  document.getElementById('content').appendChild(list);
}

// loop over each entry in stats.player_stat_summary
for(var i = 0; i < stats.player_stat_summary.length; i++ ) {
  // invoke emitStats, passing the entry's stats property.
  emitStats(stats.player_stat_summary[i].stats);
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```